# Trying to find number of possible paths going through all points exactly once starting at the center of a 5x5 array. Diagonal movement is also allowed

Tags: arrays, path

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
long long int acc = 0;

bool isValid(int x, int y, int m[5][5])
{
    if(x > -1 && x < 5 && y > -1 && y < 5 && m[x][y] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
void start(int x, int y, int m[5][5],int count)
{
    if(isValid(x,y,m))
    {
        count++;
        if(count == 25)
        {
            acc++;
        }
        else
        {
            m[x][y] = 1;
            start(x+1,y,m,count);
            start(x-1,y,m,count);
            start(x,y+1,m,count);
            start(x,y-1,m,count);
            start(x+1,y+1,m,count);
            start(x-1,y-1,m,count);
            start(x+1,y-1,m,count);
            start(x-1,y+1,m,count);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int map[5][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
        {
            map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    start(2,2,map,0);
    cout<<acc;

}
```

or another code which i tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
long long int acc = 0;
class Point
{
    public:
    int row;
    int column;
    int count;
    int map[5][5];
};

vector<Point> pts;
bool isValid(Point *b)
{
    if(b->column > -1 && b->column <5 && b->row > -1 && b->row < 5 && b->map[b->column][b->row] != 1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
void start(vector<Point> A)
{
if(A.size() == 0)
{
    cout<<acc;
}
Point *temp = &A.back();
A.pop_back();
if(isValid(temp))
{
    temp->map[temp->column][temp->row] = 1;
    temp->count = temp->count + 1;
    if(temp->count == 25)
    {
        acc++;
    }
    else
    {
        Point *p = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                p->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        p->column = temp->column + 1;
        p->row = temp->row;
        p->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*p);

        Point *q = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                q->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        q->column = temp->column - 1;
        q->row = temp->row;
        q->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*q);

        Point *r = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                r->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        r->column = temp->column;
        r->row = temp->row + 1;
        r->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*r);

        Point *s = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                s->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        s->column = temp->column;
        s->row = temp->row - 1;
        s->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*s);

        Point *t = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                t->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        t->column = temp->column + 1;
        t->row = temp->row + 1;
        t->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*t);

        Point *u = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                u->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        u->column = temp->column - 1;
        u->row = temp->row - 1;
        u->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*u);

        Point *v = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                v->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        v->column = temp->column + 1;
        v->row = temp->row - 1;
        v->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*v);

        Point *w = new Point;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++)
            {
                w->map[i][j] = temp->map[i][j];
            }
        }
        w->column = temp->column - 1;
        w->row = temp->row + 1;
        w->count = temp->count;
        A.push_back(*w);    
    }
}
cout<<A.size();
start(A);
}

int main()
{
pts.clear();
Point *p = new Point;
p->map[2][2] = 0;
p->column = 2;
p->row = 2;
p->count = 0;
cout<<p<<endl;
pts.push_back(*p);
start(pts);

}
```

the first runs for about 150 iterations and then outputs 0, to indicate no completepaths, which is definitely wrong.
the second seems an error in pointers and addresses, which i still cannot get my head around.